# Retrieve first paragraph from Wikipedia in Chinese

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I want to retrieve the first paragraph of Wikipedia in Chinese language. I found an API;

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&rawcontinue=1&format=xml&exintro=&titles=samsung
```

but it returns data in English.

How can I get data from this API in Chinese language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia is not one site but multiple. The article `Samsung` on English Wikipedia contains no Chinese text, but you are probably looking for the [corresponding page on Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E6%98%9F%E9%9B%86%E5%9B%A2). As most or all Wikipedias use the [TextExtract extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts) that you are calling above, you can simply change the domain and page title, and use the same API call as you just did:

```
http://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&rawcontinue=1&format=xml&exintro=&titles=%E4%B8%89%E6%98%9F%E9%9B%86%E5%9B%A2
```

Relevant for Chinese: According to the docs, you should also be able to chose what language variant (e.g. `zh-tw`, Taiwanese, or `zh-cn`, mainland) to fetch, using the `exvariant` parameter.

Comment: Thanks , when I am using http://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&rawcontinue=1&format=xml&exintro=&exvariant=zh-hk&titles=%E4%B8%89%E6%98%9F%E9%9B%86%E5%9B%A2 and http://zh.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&rawcontinue=1&format=xml&exintro=&exvariant=zh-tw&titles=%E4%B8%89%E6%98%9F%E9%9B%86%E5%9B%A2 , both give same result

Comment: I think zh-hk should give in traditional Chinese .